# solving $\lim \sqrt{x^2+a} dx$

Tags: integration

$F(x) = \int 1 \times \sqrt{x^2 + a} dx = x\sqrt{x^2+a} - \int x \times \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}dx = x\sqrt{x^2+a} - \int \frac{x^2+a-a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}dx = x\sqrt{x^2+a} - \int \sqrt{x^2+a} dx + a \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}$

This is all correct, but I can't understand why that last integral has a + instead of a - in front of it.

Comment: Two minuses give a plus.

Comment: Of course, but I just find one. since you divide $x^2+a-a$ to $x^2+a$ and $-a$

Comment: We are looking at $-\int \frac{(x^2+a)-a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\,dx$. This is $-\int \frac{x^2+a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\,dx -\int \frac{-a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}\,dx$. Note the double minus towards the end.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you please convert your comment to an answer? Ping me when you're done.